# OpenCV on C++/Namespace issue?

Tags: c++, opencv, namespaces

I am new to C++ so I get some trouble to use openCV on my C++ project. I'm using Xcode as an IDE.

So I used brew to install opencv using the two command lines:

```
brew install opencv3 --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb --with-contrib
brew reinstall opencv3 --HEAD --with-python3 --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb --with-contrib
```

I checked the path to add to my project to load the library using recursivity, so I added on Xcode the path for header path and library:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/**
```

I also tried to install it another way, but still got the same issue:

```
brew install opencv
```

And adding the path to:

```
/usr/local/include/**
```

Everything seems to work since the library is detected, but import is not working because I got namespace errors in the openCV files, for instance:

```
No type named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std'
No member named 'allocator_traits' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'allocator_arg_t'?
```

I checked on the internet and maybe it should be due to the the C++ language dialect or standard library, but I use GNU ++ 14 and libc++ . From what I found it should be working in that config, but I still got the issues. Do you have any ideas ?

EDIT: I don't even try to use it yet, I just used the include and print an hello:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cv.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

std::cout<<"hello";
}
```

I also tried cv.hpp instead of cv.h, still not working

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you include the correct headers? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Yeah I didn't even use opencv, just try to include it:

    #include <iostream>
#include "cv.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    std::cout<<"hello";
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using the correct #include paths, if you look at the [OpenCV Example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html), you need the following for OpenCV 3.0 to open an image:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

None of these are like the headers that you have, which are likely for older versions.

This [tutorial](https://blogs.wcode.org/2014/11/howto-setup-xcode-6-1-to-work-with-opencv-libraries/) looks like a very sensible one to get up and running with xcode, and the example at the bottom looks like a better start

Comment: Hi!

I tried the example at the bottom of the link you send me, being careful by adding the path to the given includes you showed.
But I still got the exact same issue